# “All My Files” in Finder: How to list all files on mounted DASD instead of all local files?

Tags: finder

I understand “All My Files” option in Finder lists local files only. Is there any way to list all files on mounted Directly Attached Storage Device (DASD) instead, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using the All My Files option, but yes you can, using your own search criteria.

1. Open your volume in Finder
2. Search for Any Document:

   [image]
3. Set the search location to the name of the drive:

   [image]

Alternatively, for all files (not just Documents like All My Files) you can set the search criteria by size:

[image]

You can change the view to make it match the appearance of All My Files:

[image]